# PDI. I would like to aggregate a line to csv im creating

Tags: pentaho, transformation, pdi, spoon

For make it easy, i have a table on a ddbb that i'm making the input on pdi then i want to output it as a csv but i would like to add a line before.

For example what i would look like when you open the csv:

i'm idiot

id;xxxxx;xx;xx;ddd;d

1;ddd;ddd;ddd;ddd;d

2;ds;dd;ss;dss;s

i'm using pentaho

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to achieve this would be to use two transformations, the first one create the file with the line, and the second one uses the Text file output step to add the data to the file created in the first transformation. The Text file output step allows you to check the Append, so you add the new information to the existing file.

Comment: i already have created the csv with the line (it dont change) and try to append the information coming from the data base and it just create an other csv

Comment: Are you sure the name of the file is exactly the same one? Because if the Append check was failing, then the content of the file would be overwritten, but creating a second file sounds as if the name is not exactly the same.